# Can't find R class

Tags: android

When i open eclipse, the `R class` in my project is disappeared. Why?
I've eclipse juno and the last version of android SDK.

The `R class` doesn't regenerate because there are errors in the code...
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Fix the errors on the code?, which is the error that eclipse shows?

Answer (score 3):

Try ***Project*** -> ***clean***

if this fails, **fix the errors** and **build** the project again,
the `R class` will regenerate.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to **rebuild** your entire project? You can do that with the menu item *Project -> Clean*.

Answer (score 0):

Look for errors in the XML resources; those will prevent R from being built, along with errors in the code.

The "Errors" tab in Eclipse is your friend here.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project and rebuild it

**Build/Clean project**

**Build/Rebuild project**

in android studio

thank you